# Minecraft forge Screen Rendering Error

Tags: java, minecraft, rendering, modding

So. I was playing Minecraft Forge 1.7.10, And I Had The EyeMod Mod. so I tried to turn on the phone, And...

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// This doesn't make any sense!

Time: 29/10/19 5:23 PM
Description: Rendering screen

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.server.management.ServerConfigurationManager.func_72361_f(Ljava/lang/String;)Lnet/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayerMP;
    at net.EyeMod.eyemod.gui.GuiIpod.drawApp(GuiIpod.java:328)
    at net.EyeMod.eyemod.gui.GuiIpod.func_73863_a(GuiIpod.java:226)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78480_b(EntityRenderer.java:1358)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:1001)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:898)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)

Here is the Longer Version of the error. The Crash Report Exceeded the character limit.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_5b6LGroINA2JM-1puAdIOjfCBigAmjabLY3xnWXngc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So restart the game? File a bug report with the responsible modder? What is your actual question?

Comment: Questions regarding phones are offtopic on SuperUser. See the Help Center to learn about what questions are suitable for SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the mod itself , that error is NoSuchMethodError error ( just browse it ) , the error is not in the OS but in the mod and game itself , are you using the corresponding forge version that is recommended by the mod ? if yes , are you using the latest version of the mod ? , if yes , are you using the java version recommended by mod ? have you tried to clean reinstall minecraft , forge , and the mod ?

If answer to all question above is yes and it still crash , then the error is the mod fault , report it to the mod developer .